# Oracle SQL Query Challenge - Optimize cost

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select a.header_id
from   HEADERS_STG a
where  exists (
                  select null
                  from   LINES_STG b
                  where  b.stg_header_id = a.stg_header_id
                         and ( b.status = 'IGNORE' or (b.status = 'VALID' and a.status = 'IGNORE') )
              )
```

Can you please advise me on any alternative for above Oracle SQL query. 
The problem is I have huge costs when adding new predicate: `a.status='IGNORE'`

I have B-tree Indexes on: `a.header_id (unique), a.status (nonunique), b.status (nonunique)`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Below are the execution plans. First one is without `a.status='IGNORE'` and the second one is with...

```
Plan hash value: 1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                            |  1096K|    29M|       |  1889K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN SEMI                       |                            |  1096K|    29M|       |  1889K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN                      | SYS_C0041             |  3311K|    18M|       | 19437   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   SORT UNIQUE                          |                            |  1994K|    41M|   122M|  1870K  (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   4 |    INLIST ITERATOR                     |                            |       |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| LINES_STG      |  1994K|    41M|       |   156K  (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | LINES_STG_IDX1 |  1994K|       |       | 18300   (6)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("B"."STG_HEADER_ID"="A"."STG_HEADER_ID")
       filter("B"."STG_HEADER_ID"="A"."STG_HEADER_ID")
   6 - access("B"."STATUS"='IGNORE' OR "B"."STATUS"='VALIDATED')
```

```
Plan hash value: 2

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                            |     1 |    21 |    24M  (2)| 00:01:28 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                              |                            |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | HEADERS_STG    |  3311K|    66M|  8120K  (1)| 00:00:29 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| XLINES_STG      |     1 |    22 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | LINES_STG_IDX3 |     8 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM LINES_STG" "B" WHERE "B"."STG_HEADER_ID"=:B1 AND 
              ("B"."STATUS"='IGNORE' OR :B2='IGNORE' AND "B"."STATUS"='VALIDATED')))
   3 - filter("B"."STATUS"='IGNORE' OR :B1='IGNORE' AND "B"."STATUS"='VALIDATED')
   4 - access("B"."STG_HEADER_ID"=:B1)
```

Comment: What do you want to get. Exclude something from table2? Maybe MINUS would work better?

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik Thank your for your reply. I've already tried MINUS, still bad performance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry for bad formatted text. It's a performance problem, yes.

Comment: Please publish unmodified SQL code (table names are not modified in EXPLAIN PLAN) and only 1 query. How many rows are returned by the query ? Please post also Oracle version with full 4 digits and the execution plan with actual stats with           `select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ <your SQL query without SELECT>;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS'));`

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause in the subquery is equivalent to `b.status = 'IGNORE'`, because a given row will match to itself (hence, "IGNORE"/"VALID" is covered by the simpler version).

Answer (score 0):

This is your query slightly re-written:

```
select header_id
from table1
where header_id in (select header_id from table2 where status = 'IGNORE')
   or (header_id in (select header_id from table2 where status = 'VALID')
       and status = 'IGNORE');
```

Sometimes the optimizer fails on finding a good execution plan when conditions are combined with `OR`. So, the following query may be faster for that reason:

```
select header_id
from table1
where header_id in (select header_id from table2 where status = 'IGNORE')
union
select header_id
from table1
where status = 'IGNORE'
and header_id in (select header_id from table2 where status = 'VALID');
```

Well, `UNION` is also costly, so this can just as well get slower.

There should be the following indexes:

```
create index idx1 on table1 (status, header_id);
create index idx2 on table2 (header_id, status);
```

I'd also add this index:

```
create index idx3 on table2 (status, header_id);
```

just to give the DBMS an alternative on how to access the data. (You can drop indexes afterwards, when you see they are not used.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it, however, cost looks bigger. I think I found some solution by using left join but I need to test it more...

Comment: Sorry, to hear that. Did you provide the three indexes? No matter whether your query or my queries, they should all benefit from them.

Comment: No for the moment, because I have some programs running related to.. I need to find other way. Thanks again.

Comment: @IustinBeceneagă Keep in mind that the cost is only an estimate.  The estimates are usually good, but if you're having a performance problem then they may not be accurate here.  It's always best to compare actual run times.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by rewriting the query as:

```
select hs.header_id
from HEADERS_STG hs
where exists (select 1
              from LINES_STG hs2
              where hs2.stg_header_id = hs2.stg_header_id and
                    hs2.status = 'IGNORE'
             ) or
      (hs.status = 'IGNORE' and
       exists (select 1
               from LINES_STG hs2
               where hs2.stg_header_id = hs2.stg_header_id and
                     hs2.status = 'VALID'
              )
      );
```

This wants an index on `LINES_STG(stg_header_id, status)`.  Hmmm, as I think about it, the second condition is redundant, because the logic in the first condition will match on the same row.  So, this logic should be equivalent:

```
select hs.header_id
from HEADERS_STG hs
where exists (select 1
              from LINES_STG hs2
              where hs2.stg_header_id = hs2.stg_header_id and
                    hs2.status = 'IGNORE'
             );
```

Another method is to use window functions:

```
select hs.header_id
from (select hs.*,
             sum(case when status = 'IGNORE' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by stg_header_id) as cnt_ignore
      from HEADERS_STG hs
     ) hs
where cnt_ignore > 0 ;
```

In Oracle, this might be the fastest approach.